# limiting p tag value to one line and breaking after last full word

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have limited the `<p>` tag to one line using the below code

```
<div style="width:100px;height:20px;background:lightgrey">
<p style="white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;width:100%;overflow:hidden">hello this string is a long string hello this is a long string hello this is a long string hello this is a long string hello this is a long string </p>
</div>
```

The problem I am facing is, the styling is cutting the tag contents off in the middle of a word. For example the above is displayed as:

```
hello this string i...
```

I want it to cut after the full word i.e

```
hello this string is..
```

How can I achieve that?

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2r3txe24/) shows my current attempts.

Comment: This might help https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js ?

Comment: You cannot do it with pure CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You should check [`jquery.autoellipsis` library](http://pvdspek.github.io/jquery.autoellipsis/)

`text-overflow: ellipsis;` work only for per letter truncating

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

> This keyword value indicates to display an ellipsis ('…', U+2026
>   Horizontal Ellipsis) to represent clipped text. The ellipsis is
>   displayed inside the content area, decreasing the amount of text
>   displayed. If there is not enough space to display the ellipsis, it is
>   clipped.